# So what do we use instead of PartitionMagic now that Symantec's killed it?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, symantec

Apparently, since the last time I had to do a lot of playing with partitions and images, Symantec acquired, neglected, and killed off PartitionMagic.  (Yeah, it's been a while.)  What, then, are we meant to use instead, that gives us that general behavior of *actually doing what it's goddamned supposed to* that PartitionMagic so nobly displayed?

Comment: How things have changed. These days I'd vote to close this in the blink of an eye.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are quite a few alternatives, both commercial and Open Source. One of the more popular OS programs is [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I find the gparted live CD invaluable on that front.

Comment: +1 Easy to use and free, though even Windows in its latest incarnations can finally handle most partition resize jobs just fine. Also, as Partition Magic seriously required a working backup, I always found it more efficient to just wipe and reload a machine instead anyway.

Comment: Windows can resize a partition from the end only, it cannot move a partition, or shrink it from the beginning. gparted can!

Answer (score 4):

My vote is for Gparted also.  I have a USB stick as an Ubuntu 10.04 boot disk.  Gparted let's you move and resize NTFS partitions, which is especially handy when managing windows boxes :)

Answer (score 3):

[Acronis Disk Director suite](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/diskdirector/partition-management.html)

[Paragon Partition Manager](http://www.paragon-software.com/business/pm-professional/)

Answer (score 3):

There is also a [gparted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of programs that do this, some of them have been mentioned already. If you're interested in something that also offers a compliment of other tools in addition to several partition managers you might try [MultiBoot USB](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-multiboot-usb/).

Answer (score 1):

While I myself voted for GParted, there is also [EASEUS Partition Master Home Edition](http://www.partition-tool.com/personal.htm) (Sure, not for business).

I`v been doing job with that soft, but once some errors occured (nothing was corrupt, but couldn't finish the job), I tried GParted to do the same and it succeeded.